# Node.js private method bug

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop, encapsulation

I faced a strange problem in my Node.js project. I have a class and need to hide some of his methods. MDN says that i need to put `#` at the beginning of the method name. And this is not valid! I have 13.6 Node version. Here's my code:

```
module.exports.class = class ExtendedEmbed extends MessageEmbed {
    static #validateColors(colors) {
        // Do something;
    }

    static #validateTemplates() {
        // Do something...
    }
    
    // Other methods...

    /**
     * @param {String} color 
     * @param {String} template 
     * @param {import('discord.js').MessageEmbedOptions} data 
     * @param {import('./index').ExtendedEmbedOptions} options 
     */
    constructor(color, template, data = {}, options = {}) {
        console.log(ExtendedEmbed.#validateColors(options.colors);
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
C:\Projects\EmbedUtilities\src\ExtendedEmbed.js:4
    static #validateColors(colors) {
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
```

Comment: Show more of the code.

Comment: Already edited the question

Comment: Private class fields are a stage 3 proposal as mentioned on the top of the MDN site. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields What this means is they are still being proposed and vetted to enter the Javascript core language. Node does not support them (yet). If you want to use them you need a compiler like Babel to compile your source code with this feature into something Node understands

Comment: @AndyRay [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility) says it supports them as of version 12.0.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a private method instead of the static once?

```
    private validateTemplates() {
        // Do something...
    }
```

Comment: The 'private' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files